# how do I convert .iso to .mp4 without mounting with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, mp4, iso-image, mencoder

The problem is - I want to convert .iso with dvd to .mp4 (h264/ac3), but I cannot mount it via mount -o loop, because I'm on a virtual machine that doesn't allow to do that.

Googling doesn't help.

For now I'm trying to use mencoder for the task, but it's hard for me to convert all the parameters from ffmpeg-style to mencoder style.

Comment: You can extract .iso files with xorriso.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do this with [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/), which comes in both GUI and CLI flavours and uses ffmpeg on the backend to do the transcoding.

```
HandBrakeCLI -Z "High Profile" -i a_movie.iso -o a_movie.mp4
```

Alternatively, if you have some funky FFmpeg voodoo that you can't easily replicate in HandBrakeCLI, you could mount the ISO locally and copy the VIDEO_TS folder up to the server that you want to do the conversion on.

Comment: If you want to know what other profiles are available, use:

_HandBrakeCLI -z_