# Convert BluRay iso to mkv or mp4 without changing resolution? (e.g. using Handbrake)

Tags: audio, video, video-conversion, blu-ray, handbrake

I've got a .iso file of a BluRay movie, and I want to convert that to a single .mp4 or .mkv file.

After searching around I came across [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/329361/446921) to a similar question. But when I use the given command line, I only get a 20 sec video file with a movie band/label animation. I guess it's some introduction animation that is at the start of the BluRay content before the actual movie.

Now, I tried the GUI version of Handbrake, and there I saw indeed a bunch of number of titles, which appear to be video contents, one of which was 1 hour 42 min, so I guess that's the movie.

However, this is where the headache starts. I am now confronted with tons of confusing options. Such as: Anamorphic, Modulus, Source resolution (which is fixed 1920x1080 in this case) versus Storage Size which is 1920 x 804 for some reason (why I would want to store it in a different size, in a different aspect ratio even, is beyond me), Cropping, Subtitles as *bitmaps* instead of textual (SRT) content, Constant or Variable Framerate, et cetera et cetera.

I am afraid I am entering a world of pain here.

Rather than diving into the depths of BluRay specific technicalities, two questions:

1. Am I right in thinking that somewhere inside this BluRay ISO thing, there is a piece of video content with 1920x1080 resolution, that contains the actual movie and one or more corresponding audio tracks. And perhaps other streams or metadata like subtitles, chapter info, DVD/BluRay menus, separate cutscenes, and whatnot. But at least there **should be a normal piece of video and audio content in there containing the main movie itself, correct?**
2. Can I somehow extract this video and audio content into a .mkv or .mp4 file **without changing its resolution or framerate?**
   Preberably I'd do so without re-encoding it, so basically just extract and copy the raw video + audio content. Is that possible?

Comment: “Am I right ..” - Depends on the ISO;  if you have the raw ISO why are you doing anything to it?

Comment: @Ramhound I cannot easily play an ISO file. Well, I can on macOS (but not with all players) and I also want to play it on my iPad. And I also want to have to have the option to re-encode it to a smaller format. What do you mean with raw ISO, are there other kinds of ISOs? When I double click this ISO, it is mounted and contains all sorts of files which I don't recognize.

Comment: ISO is the image of the bluray disk from start of the disk to the end (also used for DVD and CD) ... the files are contained inside the ISO .... the ISO contains the whole file system of the bluray disk ... you could use a burner to put the ISO onto a physical disk

Comment: @jsotola Thanks, I understand the concept of an ISO image containing files, but I don't want have anything to do with physical disks (in fact I don't even have any optical media devices). I meant "does it contain the stream" more on a logical level. As in, is there a straight piece of video + audio content (encoded into multiple files or something) that I can extract and put into a single mkv or mp4 file. When looking in the ISO contents, I don't see one single large video file for example.